# Desvio padrão JAVA

Tags: java

Aqui estão meus método para calcular o desvio padrão, que por algum motivo desconhecido por mim não funciona (deixei meu método de teste aqui em baixo também).

```
public strictfp Double getMedia(List<Double> valor) {
    try {
        return getSoma(valor) / valor.size();
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The list has null values");
    }
}

public strictfp Double getSoma(List<Double> valor) {
    Double soma = 0D;
    for (int i = 0; i < valor.size(); i++) {
        soma += valor.get(i);
    }
    return soma;
}

public strictfp Double getDesvioPadrao(List<Double> valor) {
    Double media = getMedia(valor);
    int tam = valor.size();
    Double desvPadrao = 0D;
    for (Double vlr : valor) {
        Double aux = vlr - media;
        desvPadrao += aux * aux;
    }
    return Math.sqrt(desvPadrao / tam);
}
```

#

Método de teste:

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Test
private void TesteDesvioPadrao() {
    List<Double> valor = new ArrayList<Double>();
    valor.add(13.0);
    valor.add(23.0);
    valor.add(4.0);
    valor.add(2.0);
    valor.add(11.0);
    valor.add(12.0);

    assertEquals(new Double(7.467708), ilbt.getDesvioPadrao(valor));

}
```

Comment: Qual o erro? A pergunta não está clara

Comment: Qual o problema que está tendo? Pela sua pergunta não da para saber do que você precisa.

Comment: Quando eu rodo meu método de teste, "initializationError"

Comment: Favor não colocar RESOLVIDO no título, o site não funciona assim. De uma olhada no [tour]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O erro está no cálculo do desvio padrão, no final do método **`getDesvioPadrao`**.

Nele você retorna a raiz quadrada da divisão da variância pelo tamanho da coleção. Como você está calculando o desvio padrão de **uma amostra**, deveria ser o tamanho da coleção **subtraindo 1**.

```
public strictfp Double getDesvioPadrao(List<Double> valor) {
    Double media = getMedia(valor);
    int tam = valor.size();
    Double desvPadrao = 0D;
    for (Double vlr : valor) {
        Double aux = vlr - media;
        desvPadrao += aux * aux;
    }
    return Math.sqrt(desvPadrao / (tam - 1));
}
```

<sup>[**Veja funcionando no repl.it**](https://repl.it/@jfbueno/SphericalSurprisedIcelandicsheepdog)</sup>

Comment: Obrigado, realmente faltava esse detalhe, porém o erro initializationError[Runner JUnit4] ainda persiste

Comment: @Strigi Por favor, não adicione "resolvido" no título da pergunta. A única forma de sinalizar que a pergunte tem uma resposta é marcando alguma resposta como correta.